# CognitiveService Face - AddPersonFaceAsync requires GUID (instead of people's name) as second param?

Tags: .net, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying out Microsoft Cognitive Services Face API now, looking at here as reference: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/face-api/documentation/face-api-how-to-topics/howtoidentifyfacesinimage

Now, I don't understand why the second parameter for AddPersonFaceAsync is taking in GUID. My logic tells me that you would want to add the groupId of the person, and the name of the person (the same name that is used when calling CreatePersonAsync). But the function requires that I pass in a GUID?

What GUID do I use here? Do I just generate anything? How is that GUID is going to be associated with the person's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a person that person is assigned an ID (a GUID) by the API on the server side, and that ID is returned from the CreatePerson method.  You can see this in step 2.1 in the returned friend1 variable.  In future calls interacting with that person you pass in the ID assigned to that person.

The name of the person is just metadata display name, not used to identify the person.  What if you had 2 friends with the same name?

It may help to look at the raw REST API to better understand the input and output of the APIs.  See https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523c.